# Question about selenium/beautifulsoup html parsing

Tags: html, selenium, parsing, beautifulsoup, webdriverwait

HTML

```
<span class="itemName tiny">foo</span>
    <span class="fr">
        <span id="2kCf5PSJ0vuykePDtnKrGOKvepUq1suWY5xrArwfAEVl2RmP8xyaq388rH4_slash_63OS||CAD||PPR||CA" class="itemValue privacy valueTiny">bar</span>
        <span class="currencyType ">CAD</span>
    </span>
```

My code

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
balance = soup.find(text="foo").findNext('span id')
print(balance) <--- expecting "bar"
schequing = balance.text
```

but balance is always empty, and I get this error.

```
File "C:/Users/thomas/PycharmProjects/test/mainapp/main.py", line 223, in bills
schequing = balance.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Does anyone know how to parse the html with beautiful soup?  My intention here is to find  with value foo, which is unique, then get the next  tags value, which should be bar.

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a *dynamic element* so you have to use *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be visible* and then parse the html as follows:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("your_url")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='itemValue privacy valueTiny'][text()='bar']")))
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
balance = soup.find(text="foo").findNext('span id')
print(balance)
```